# Images in android studio html files

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, android-studio

I am making a game called "shades" and I want to learn how to put Javascript files in android studio. If someone could give me a detailed guide with examples that'd be great. I am copying and pasting a game that I have made and I am confused about which files I would find my images. Please help me find out where to drag my images into.

[My screen right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tda3h.png)

just to be specific, this is how I make an image in Javascript.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "image.png";
```

Where in my files (found on the left side of the screen in "My screen right now") do I drag my images into?

Comment: Can help to escalate? Are you expecting to embed your html web page into Android Apps?

Comment: Put your files (HTML, CSS and javascript) in 'assets' folder. Images also go there.